# Use addEventListener() to access multiple objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my checkboxes's label to highlight when on and off (like a IRL switch) and I'm not figuring out how to reach all of them without having to make a listener for each of them (I belive there must be some way)

Checkboxes be like:

```
<label id="labeltest"><input id="checkboxtest" type="checkbox" name="diet" value="Egg" hidden/>Egg</label>
```

JS be like:

```
var labeltest = document.getElementById("labeltest")

labeltest.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (this.firstChild.checked) {
        this.classList.remove("unchecked")
        this.classList.add("checked")
    } else if (this.firstChild.checked === false) {
        this.classList.remove("checked")
        this.classList.add("unchecked")
    }
});
```

I've tried with class instead of ID but didn't work

Also tried something like this with classes to make `labeltest` an array:

```
labeltest.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    (FUNCTION HERE)
});
```

But didn't work either

Comment: Though this particular case can be resolved with pure CSS, the common solution to what is asked is [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any JavaScript to accomplish this.

If you reorder your input and labels like this:

```
<input id="diet-egg" type="checkbox" name="diet" value="Egg" hidden/>
<label for="diet-egg">Egg</label>
```

**Important:** Be sure that the `for` attribute value matches the `id` of the input the label is connected to. This enables checking and unchecking the checkbox by clicking the `<label>` element.

Then you can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+` to define the styles of the label whenever the input is checked and unchecked.

```
input + label {
  /* unchecked label styles */
}

input:checked + label {
  /* checked label styles */
}
```

Comment: Thank you Emiel! That worked perfectly =) I was overcomplicating things

FYI: I've tested the `hidden` as I shown above, and it still works, passes the value as bool and triggers the css also, maybe it is supported now (? idk, only tested on Chrome

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for pointing that out. I checked again and `hidden` seems to fall under [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) which are supported on input tags. So yeah, you can use them.